# I need to do some modifications in a part of a sentence in a txt file with forms with PHP

Tags: php

I really need your help!
In advance sorry for my english...

I need to edit a .txt file with a PHP file, the modification in the txt file need to come from a form with the method "post"so,
my txt file look like this :

```
tour.name = something

image_foo = name of the image
```

I need to read the txt file line by line, split every line as an array; and split every line in an other array like
tour.name <=  array key one  /  " = " <= explode the sentence with " = " / something <= array key two,  My code need to check if array key one == "tour.name" and if it's "tour.name" change the "something" with the $_POST['tourname'].

In my PHP file i've wrote that :

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label for="tourname">Titre:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tourname" name="tourname"><br><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
$myArray = array();

$file = fopen("file.txt", "r+");

while (!feof($file)) {
    $line = fgets($file);
    $myArray[] = explode(' = ', $line);
 }

 $arr_length = count($myArray);

$actualTitle = $myArray[0][1];
$modifiedTitle = $_POST['tourname'];
$modifiedTitle .= PHP_EOL;

for ($i=0; $i<$arr_length; $i++){
    switch($myArray[0][0]){
        case "tour.name":
                $myArray[0][1] = str_replace($actualTitle, $modifiedTitle, $myArray[0][1]);
                fseek($file, 12);
                fwrite($file, $modifiedTitle);
                break;
    }
}

 fclose($file);
?>
```

PS: My code need to be not precise like mine in : `$myArray[0][0]` because the code need to be modulable, the txt file can be changed and not have the same number of lines, and not in the same order.... The code need to check if the first part of the sentence = "tour.name" but the tour.name in a future can be on the line 30 for example.

If someone can help me please!
**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly that you simply wish to replace an existing value from a `key=value` pair where `key==tour.name` then you can simplify your code quite drastically. I notice that you use a `switch` expression which suggests that your end goal is beyond what you describe in the question but the following can easily be modified to accomodate...

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['tourname'] ) ){
        # assign POSTed value as variable for convenience
        $tourname=$_POST['tourname'];
        
        # always easier to use the full path
        $file=__DIR__ .'/file.txt';
        
        # read the file into an array - makes it easier to read, line by line
        $lines=file( $file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );
        
        #iterate through all lines
        foreach( $lines as $i=> $line ){
            # split the line by the delimiter `=`
            list( $param, $value )=explode( '=', $line );
            
            # basic comparison test
            if( trim( $param ) == 'tour.name' ){
                # find the position in the array where this current line occurs
                $pos=array_search($line,$lines);
                
                #generate new content using POSTed value
                $line=sprintf('%s=%s',trim($param),trim($tourname));
                
                #splice the new value into the original position
                array_splice($lines,$pos,1,$line);
            }
        }
        # save the text file
        file_put_contents($file,implode(PHP_EOL,$lines));
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>edit textfile</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='tourname' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```